# segmentation fault for 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I want to define a 2D array of very big size. But it is giving me segmentation fault?

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main () {
       int i;
       int temp[4000][5000];
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          printf ("Hello World\n");
      }
  }
```

Can anyone please suggest me some other way? Is there some problem with memory initialization? Thanks in advance

Comment: There's only a limited amount of space for automatic variables, and your array doesn't fit. Make it a global variable.

Comment: Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes on your system you are trying to create an array that requires `80 MB` of space. Use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allocate the whole table in only one array but you won't be able to access array data with indices using two square brackets:

```
int * temp = malloc(4000*5000*sizeof(int));
```

to access the element (i,j) where previously you wrote `temp[i][j]`, now you should now compute the index the following way:

```
temp[i*5000+j];
```

and do not forget to free the memory allocated for your table afterward:

```
free(temp);
```

Comment: You can. You just need to set pointers to correct parts of array.

Answer (score 3):

```
int temp[4000][5000];
```

That's a VERY BIG array, way bigger than the normal size of stack, you get a segmentation fault because of [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables). Consider using dynamic allocation instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic allocated arrays for such big arrays.

Try:

```
int* temp[4000];
for(i = 0; i < 4000; ++i) temp[i] = malloc(5000 * sizeof(int));
...
for(i = 0; i < 4000; ++i) free(temp[i]).
```

Whole program with error checking:

```
int main () {
    int i, j;
    int* temp[4000];
    for (i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = malloc(5000 * sizeof(int));
        if (temp[i] == NULL)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) free(temp[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf ("Hello World\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4000; ++i) free(temp[i]);
}
```

[Here](http://tianrunhe.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/allocate-a-two-dimensional-array-using-one-call-of-malloc-in-c/) you can find function which would use single malloc call to allocate two dimension array.

And simpler version of my own:

```
int main () {
    int i, j;
    int* temp[4000];
    int* array = malloc(4000 * 5000 * sizeof(int));
    if (malloc_tmp == NULL) exit(1);
    for (i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = array + (i * 5000);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf ("Hello World\n");
    }

    free(temp[0]);
}
```

Comment: That looks horrible. One single allocation should be all that's needed.

Comment: @Ari This woking fine.. Is there a way, when i can malloc for complete 5000*4000?? in a single line

Comment: @Vishwadeep `malloc(4000*5000*sizeof(int))` is sufficient

Comment: @Kunal But then you need to set correct pointers to `tmp[0] ... tmp[3999]`.

Comment: @Ari That is simple pointer arithmetic. You could always do `tmp + row_no*4000+ col_no`

Comment: @Kunal I agree. But it is easier to write `tmp[2][3]` than `tmp[2 * ROW_SIZE + 3]`. You made mistake writing you example. You should write I think `tmp + row_no * 5000 + col_no`.