# Generate Random Matrices to External Files in C

Tags: c, file-io, matrix

I want to generate two matrices with random values and store it into two different files. I have compiled this code and it works perfectly up until MAX_ROW and MAX_COL equals to 600 each. However, values above it trigger Windows error which saying "generate.exe has stopped working. Windows can check online for solution to the problem."

I am very confused, please help me.

Thank you.

Here is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_VAL 10
#define MAX_ROW 500
#define MAX_COL 500

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int matA[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
    int matB[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
    FILE *out;
    srand(time(NULL)); // Random seed
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROW; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < MAX_COL; j++)
        {
            matA[i][j] = rand()%MAX_VAL; // Fill with random number from 0 - 9
            matB[i][j] = rand()%MAX_VAL; // Fill with random number from 0 - 9
        }
    }
    out=fopen("matA.mat", "w");
    fprintf(out, "%d %d", MAX_ROW, MAX_COL);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROW; i++)
    {
        fprintf(out, "\n");
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_COL; j++)
            fprintf(out, "%d ", matA[i][j]);
    }
    fclose(out);
    out=fopen("matB.mat", "w");
    fprintf(out, "%d %d", MAX_ROW, MAX_COL);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROW; i++)
    {
        fprintf(out, "\n");
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_COL; j++)
            fprintf(out, "%d ", matB[i][j]);
    }
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Solved the problem. Turns out there was stack overflow since too much memory allocated on the main stack. I solved the problem by moving the matrix variables into global variables, hence removing it from the heap.

Comment: There are *hundreds* of similar faults on SO. [See here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584758/segmentation-fault-for-2d-arrays).

Comment: `malloc` + `free` are fine things, but if it's just the tiny bit of code you showed, using global variables should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ready access to a Windows machine at the moment, but compiling your code on OS X, I was able to reproduce your problem, except that for me the "magic threshold" was reached at 1023x1023 matrix elements, beyond which I get a Segmentation fault.

I think, what's happening here is that you are overflowing the stack with those huge, local variables. Simply turning them into global or static variables made the error go away for me. Anyhow, a better approach, as already mentioned by lodizer, would be to avoid allocating those huge temporaries altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing one row at a time, and not bothering to store the whole matrix in a buffer.

Now that others have chimed in I agree it is a the perfect irony, a stack overflow:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

has a decent description.

Comment: Yeah that should also works! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might hit stack size limit. It is around 2M (?) or so default. With two matrices 600*600*4 you ask for about 2.5M (check the numbers, please).

Moral of the story: either use heap for large objects, or set larger stack size via compiler options